# ftp_get() working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(300);//for setting 
$path='/PickUpOld';
$ftp_server='xxxxxx.com';
$ftp_server_port="xx";
$ftp_user_name='xxxxxxx';
$ftp_user_pass="xxxxxxxx";

// set up a connection to ftp server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_server_port); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$ps = ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
// check connection and login result
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$ps)) { 
    echo "Fail</br>";
} else {
    echo "Success</br>";
    // enabling passive mode
    ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true );
    // get contents of the current directory
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
    // output $contents
 $local_file = 'rana.php';
 $server_file = 'PickUpOld/test.php';
 if ( ftp_get( $conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
     echo "WOOT! Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}



}

// close the FTP connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

I am trying to copy files one server to another. This Script working fine on localhost, but not working on Live server.
Please share your thoughts where i am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to make sure that the directory on your server that is receiving the files has proper write permissions.  I suggest CHMOD the dir to 777 to make sure that it works.

Comment: I already have 777 permissions of receiving files.

Comment: are you facing some errors on server?

Comment: No, i didnt get any eeors